# Working on Power bi but the data isn't populating on the dashboard

Tags: powerbi

I am working on power bi and my Dax + schema is OK but the data isn't populating on the dashboard(visualise).
The following is the picture of one the report I designed but the data is not populating.

[image]

Kindly, guide me what am i getting it wrong. Will really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you add an example of what is not populating? What should the graph be?

Comment: Use a table to confirm the data is what you expect. In fact post a data sample from your table in text form and explain how you expect it to be visualised.